Wine - failed to init Gecko
I was trying to install a Windows program, but this error makes it unable to proceed (apparently it uses iexplorer to show license agreement, which I cannot accept if it's not shown):
$ wine installer.exe
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0009:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE

I have made a fresh 32-bit wineprefix and executed the installer using
$ env WINEPREFIX=/home/<username>/.local/share/wineprefixes/wine32 wine installer.exe

but I'm getting the same errors.
I think I have both, 32- and 64-bit versions of gecko?
$ ls /usr/share/wine/gecko/
wine_gecko-2.47-x86_64.msi  wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi

When I run iexplorer it opens up and seems working, but I get this in console
$ wine iexplore
003d:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0009:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
0009:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData StdMarshal ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d

I kindly ask for help.
